# Find first common number where X mod Y == 0 for a set of numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I apologize if the question is confusing, I don't know how else I could ask it. This is a programming related task but since the question I have is mathematic in nature, I figured I'd ask the question here.

I have a set of $9$ unique numbers where all numbers are $<1000$ but $>0$. I am looking for the first number $X$ that satisfies the property $XmodY==0$ where $Y$ is a number from the set. For $X$, this property has to be satisfied for every single number. For example, If my set consists of the numbers ${2,4,6,8}$, the first number $X$ that would satisfy the above property for all numbers at the same time would be $24$. Brute forcing this is trivial for a small set of numbers but impossible for large sets.

Can anyone push me in the right direction here?

Comment: I think you mean the "least common multiplier of the numbers in the set". Using the gcd, you can efficiently determine it recursively using the formula $a\cdot b=lcm(a,b)\cdot \gcd(a,b)$

Comment: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).